# Disable multiple document upload in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, file-upload

I have a document library and it has a workflow associated with it. That workflow generates some automatic 3-digit serial number. If I add multiple documents then that workflow is unable to generate numbers correctly. So, Can anyone please provide me way to disable multiple upload option.
I also want to deactivate drag and drop to internet explorer feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to disable multiple document upload option using SPD after modifying in masterpage and applying some of the javascript code that including hide or delete multiple upload option.

Please go through this article  [How to Disable Multiple File Upload in SharePoint](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/05/how-to-disable-multiple-file-upload-in-sharepoint.html) and let me know is it the right approach for you?.

Comment: I already gone through this. I want to disable it for a single document library. I added content editor webpart and added scripts in HTML source but it does not works for me.I have SharePoint 2013 environment. I think that might be the reason.